# How to setup VueJs vite version (not Vue CLI) with Django

Tags: django, vue.js

I have seen many people set up Vue with django using the Vue CLI, it is now deprecated.
I tried to set it up with the new Vue way 'npm init vue@latest' that uses Vite, but wasnt successfull.
I have been using the Vue CDN but it lacks the components stuff

Comment: Can you explain what issues you had when using Vite?  a Django backend, like most backends, are agnostic to the frontend they connect to.  There is no special setup or relationship that needs to be created.  They run separately and communicate through network calls.  What specific trouble did you have with your installation attempt?

Comment: I actually want to make static files served by Django, with the build vue command

Comment: Did you gave a read to some queries on your favorite search engine? https://www.ericsdevblog.com/posts/create-a-modern-application-with-django-and-vue-1/